# Pinia state not updating UI as expected

Tags: firebase, vue.js, pinia

I have this Vue page that is supposed to show website inquiry submissions. There is a dropdown to pick the website (stored in a pin store) and a sidebar to pick the form the user chooses to see the submissions for. When the dropdown value gets changed, the form choices and submissions should reload. When the form choice is changed, the submissions need to reload. However, when the website dropdown is changed, the submissions don't reload, and it shows the submissions for the previous website.

Here is the page:

```html
<template>
    <h1>Forms</h1>
    <div class="wrapper" v-if="forms.length > 0">
        <div class="form-picker">
            <button v-for="(form, index) in forms" :key="form.id" @click="selectForm(index)"
                :class="{ 'selected': selectedFormIndex === index }" class="action">
                {{ form.name }}
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="submissions">
            <h2>Submissions</h2>
            <h4>Filters and Sorting</h4>
            <div class="filter-row-wrapper">
                <div class="filter-row">
                    <button class="filter" @click="toggleDateSort" :class="{ 'applied-filter': dateSort !== 0 }">
                        <h3>Submission Date</h3>
                        <span v-if="dateSort == 1">&#9650;</span>
                        <span v-if="dateSort == 2">&#9660;</span>
                    </button>
                    <button class="filter" @click="toggleUnread" :class="{ 'applied-filter': applyUnreadFilter }">
                        <h3>Unread</h3>
                    </button>
                    <button class="filter" @click="toggleFlagged" :class="{ 'applied-filter': applyFlaggedFilter }">
                        <h3>Flagged</h3>
                    </button>
                    <button class="filter" :class="{ 'applied-filter': emailFilter }" @click="focusEmailFilter">
                        <h3>Email</h3>
                        <p contenteditable ref="emailFilterElementRef" @input="
                            emailFilter = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement).innerText
                            ">{{ emailFilter }}</p>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="submissions-grid">
                <FormSubmissionCard v-for="submission in filtered" :key="submission.id" class="submission"
                    :website-id="websiteDataStore.websites[websiteDataStore.currentWebsiteIndex].id"
                    :formId="forms[selectedFormIndex].id" :submission="submission" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <h2 v-else>You don't have any forms yet.</h2>
</template>
```

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { getFormSubmissions, getFormTitles } from '@/methods/db/forms';
import type { Form } from '@/models/form';
import { useWebsiteDataStore } from '@/stores/websiteDataStore';
import { computed, onMounted, ref, watch, type Ref } from 'vue';
const websiteDataStore = useWebsiteDataStore()

const forms: Ref<Form[]> = ref([])
let submissions: Ref<any[]> = ref([])
const selectedFormIndex = ref()
const dateSort = ref(0)
const applyUnreadFilter = ref(false)
const applyFlaggedFilter = ref(false)
const emailFilter = ref('')
const emailFilterElementRef = ref<null | HTMLElement>(null);



const filtered = computed(() => {

    const newArray = submissions.value.filter((submission) => {
        if (applyUnreadFilter.value && submission.read) {
            return false
        }
        if (applyFlaggedFilter.value && !submission.flagged) {
            return false
        }
        if (emailFilter.value !== '' && (submission.email !== emailFilter.value)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true
    })
    if (dateSort.value) {
        newArray.sort((a, b) => {
            if (dateSort.value === 1) {
                return a.date_submitted - b.date_submitted
            } else {
                return b.date_submitted - a.date_submitted
            }
        })
    }
    return newArray
})

const focusEmailFilter = () => {
    if (emailFilter.value === '') {
        emailFilterElementRef.value?.focus();
    }
    else {
        emailFilter.value = ''
    }
};




onMounted(async () => {
    console.log("mounted")
    websiteDataStore.$subscribe(async () => {
        console.log("subscribed")
        forms.value = await getFormTitles(
            websiteDataStore.websites[websiteDataStore.currentWebsiteIndex].id
        )
        selectedFormIndex.value = 0
    })
})

watch(selectedFormIndex, async () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-ref-as-operand
    submissions = getFormSubmissions(
        websiteDataStore.websites[websiteDataStore.currentWebsiteIndex].id,
        forms.value[selectedFormIndex.value].id
    )
})





const selectForm = (index: number) => {
    selectedFormIndex.value = index
}

const toggleDateSort = () => {
    if (dateSort.value === 2) {
        dateSort.value = 0
    } else {
        dateSort.value++
    }

}
const toggleUnread = () => {
    applyUnreadFilter.value = !applyUnreadFilter.value

}
const toggleFlagged = () => {
    applyFlaggedFilter.value = !applyFlaggedFilter.value

}
</script>
```

```css
<style scoped>
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.submissions {
    padding: 0 5%;
    width: 100%;

}

.form-picker {
    background: var(--color-primary);
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem;
    flex-direction: column;
    border-radius: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .wrapper {
        flex-direction: row;
    }

    .form-picker {
        width: fit-content;
    }
}



.filter-row-wrapper {
    overflow-x: auto;
    margin: auto;
}

.filter-row {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    gap: .25rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    width: fit-content;
    margin: auto;
}

.filter-row * {
    display: flex;
    gap: .5rem;
    align-items: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.applied-filter {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.submissions-grid {
    display: grid;


    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));


    align-items: center;
    gap: 1rem;
}


.action {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
}

.selected {
    border: 4px solid var(--color-secondary);
}

.submission {
    background-color: var(--color-primary);
    color: var(--color-secondary);
    border-radius: 18px;
    width: 100%;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    .form-picker {
        background: var(--color-secondary);
    }



    .submission {
        background-color: var(--color-secondary);
        color: var(--color-primary);
    }

    .selected {
        border: 4px solid var(--color-secondary);
        outline: 4px solid var(--color-primary);
    }

    .applied-filter {
        background-color: var(--color-secondary);
        color: var(--color-primary);
    }
}
</style>
```

Here is the pin store:

```
import { Website, WebsiteContentGroup, WebsiteContentGroupItem } from '@/models/websites'
import { collection, getDocs, getFirestore, onSnapshot, query, where } from 'firebase/firestore'
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import { ref, watch, type Ref } from 'vue'

export const useWebsiteDataStore = defineStore('website', () => {
  const db = getFirestore()

  const currentUserId = ref('')

  const websites = ref<Website[]>([])
  const currentWebsiteIndex: Ref<number> = ref(0)
  const contentGroups = ref<WebsiteContentGroup[]>([])

  watch(currentWebsiteIndex, updateContentGroups)

  async function updateContentGroups() {
    try {
      const contentGroupCollectionRef = collection(
        db,
        `websites/${websites.value[currentWebsiteIndex.value].id}/content`
      )
      onSnapshot(contentGroupCollectionRef, (snapshot) => {
      contentGroups.value = []
      snapshot.forEach(async (doc) => {
        
        const data = doc.data()
        contentGroups.value.push(
          new WebsiteContentGroup({
            id: doc.id,
            name: data.name,
            items: [],
            description: data.description,
            status_choices: data.status_choices,
            order: data.order,
            accepted_file_types: data.accepted_file_types,
          })
          
        )
        const contentGroupDataRef = collection(
          db,
          `${contentGroupCollectionRef.path}/${doc.id}/data`
        )
        const contentGroupItems =
          contentGroups.value[contentGroups.value.findIndex((item) => item.id === doc.id)].items
        contentGroupItems.splice(0)

        onSnapshot(contentGroupDataRef, (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
            
            if (change.type === 'added') {
              contentGroupItems.push(
                new WebsiteContentGroupItem({
                  id: change.doc.id,
                  content: change.doc.data().content,
                  title: change.doc.data().title,
                  image_urls: change.doc.data().image_urls,
                  description: change.doc.data().description,
                  price: change.doc.data().price,
                  status_index: change.doc.data().status_index,
                })
              )
            }
            if (change.type === 'modified') {
              contentGroupItems[contentGroupItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === change.doc.id)] =
                new WebsiteContentGroupItem({
                  id: change.doc.id,
                  content: change.doc.data().content,
                  title: change.doc.data().title,
                  image_urls: change.doc.data().image_urls,
                  description: change.doc.data().description,
                  price: change.doc.data().price,
                  status_index: change.doc.data().status_index,
                })
            }
            if (change.type === 'removed') {
              contentGroupItems.splice(
                contentGroupItems.findIndex((item) => item.id === change.doc.id),
                1
              )
            }
            contentGroupItems.sort((a, b) => {
              return (
                contentGroups.value[contentGroups.value.findIndex((item) => item.id === doc.id)]
                  .order.indexOf(a.id) -
                contentGroups.value[contentGroups.value.findIndex((item) => item.id === doc.id)]
                  .order.indexOf(b.id)
              )
            })
          })
        })
      })
      })


    } catch (error) {
      return
    }
  }

  async function init(userId: string) {
    currentUserId.value = userId

    const websiteCollectionRef = collection(db, 'websites')
    const userWebsites = query(websiteCollectionRef, where('users', 'array-contains', userId))
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(userWebsites)
    websites.value = []

    try {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        websites.value.push(new Website(doc.data().url, doc.id))
      })
      await updateContentGroups()
    } catch (error) {
      return
    }
  }

  return {
    websites,
    currentWebsiteIndex,
    contentGroups,
    init
  }
})
```

Here is where the forms and submissions are fetched:

```
export const getFormTitles = async (websiteId: string): Promise<Form[]> => {
  NProgress.start()
  const formsRef = collection(getFirestore(), `websites/${websiteId}/forms`)
  const forms = await getDocs(formsRef)
  const formsArray = forms.docs.map((form) => {
    return new Form(form.id, form.data().name);
  })
  NProgress.done()
  return formsArray;
}

export const getFormSubmissions = (websiteId: string, formId: string) => {
    NProgress.start()
    const submissionsRef = collection(getFirestore(), `websites/${websiteId}/forms/${formId}/submissions`)
    const submissionsArray = ref<any[]>([])

    // Creating the listener
    onSnapshot(submissionsRef, (submissions) => {
        submissionsArray.value = submissions.docs.map((submission) => {
            const res = submission.data()
            res.id = submission.id
            return res;
        });
        
        NProgress.done()
    });

    return submissionsArray;
};
```